# Node.js jsftp delete directory

Tags: node.js, ftp, ftp-client

Is there a way to remove a directory (folder) from a ftp location using `jsftp`?

I only found how to create a new directory...

```
Ftp.raw("mkd", "/new_dir", function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err); 
});
```

If not, what else can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Since it uses raw FTP commands, wouldn't it just be `Ftp.raw("dele", ...`? Check out the [raw command list](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm)

Comment: Works using `rmd`. You should post the comment as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it uses raw FTP commands, it'd just be

```
Ftp.raw("dele", ...
```

#### Common commands

- ABOR -> abort a file transfer
- CWD -> change working directory
- DELE -> delete a remote file
- LIST -> list remote files
- MDTM -> return the modification time of a file
- MKD -> make a remote directory
- NLST -> name list of remote directory
- PASS -> send password
- PASV -> enter passive mode
- PORT -> open a data port
- PWD -> print working directory
- QUIT -> terminate the connection
- RETR -> retrieve a remote file
- RMD -> remove a remote directory
- RNFR -> rename from
- RNTO -> rename to
- SITE -> site-specific commands
- SIZE -> return the size of a file
- STOR -> store a file on the remote host
- TYPE -> set transfer type
- USER -> send username

#### Less common commands

- ACCT -> send account information
- APPE -> append to a remote file
- CDUP -> CWD to the parent of the current directory
- HELP -> return help on using the server
- MODE -> set transfer mode
- NOOP -> do nothing
- REIN -> reinitialize the connection
- STAT -> return server status
- STOU -> store a file uniquely
- STRU -> set file transfer structure
- SYST -> return system type

[Source](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm)